# Keeping unit tests isolated in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm just getting started with Java, and I'm confused about how to unit test Java classes while still keeping everything isolated. Specifically, I'm wondering how I might test a method like `createProgram` in this example:

```
package com.example.app;

import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

import com.example.data_models.Program;

public class ProgramCreator {
    private PersistenceManagerFactory pm_factory;

    public ProgramCreator(PersistenceManagerFactory pm_factory) {
        this.pm_factory = pm_factory;
    }

    public void createProgram(String name, String instructor, double price) {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();

        try {
            pm.makePersistent(new Program(name, instructor, price));
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

    private PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager()
    {
        return this.pm_factory.getPersistenceManager();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I can mock out the persistence manager factory using a library like `mockito` and use that to test that the `makePersistent` method is getting called with the right arguments, but how do I check that the fields of the program data model are correct while still keeping everything isolated? I don't want to rely on the program object's getter methods, as that would result in my unit tests for `ProgramCreator` being reliant on the `Program` class being correct. What do I do in this situation? (With Ruby, I'd probably just stub out the `new` method of the `Program` class. Is something like that possible in Java?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating an object (Program) in **createProgram** method you are creating tight coupling between the objects. Instead delegate the work of creation to a factory and you can mock the factory in your unit test. This would mean we would be testing only what **createProgram** method is doing and nothing else. Trying to unit test code could give us indications to re-design/re-factor the code.

```
public class ProgramCreator {
    private PersistenceManagerFactory pm_factory;
    private ProgramFactory p_factory;

    public ProgramCreator(PersistenceManagerFactory pm_factory, ProgramFactory pFactory) {
        this.pm_factory = pm_factory;
        this.p_factory = pFactory;
    }

    public void createProgram(String name, String instructor, double price) {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            pm.makePersistent(p_Factory.createProgram(name, instructor, price));
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But then wouldn't my object be coupled to the factory? Do I need to use dependency injection here as well?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yes, dependency injection of the program factory should be the way to go about it. I have edited my response above to be clear.

Comment: Hmm, okay that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

A unit in is not necessarily limited to a single class, it is the smallest set of classes that work together. So there is nothing wrong with using the getters from `Program` while testing `ProgramCreator`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to test everything, everywhere.

Do as you say: mock the appropriate code to test `createProgram` and see if the results of that are as you expect them to be (aka: there has been a program persisted with the given fields).

You don't have to necessarily test that you actually create a new `Program` that has those fields. You could just as well test in a different method whether or not `new Program(name, instructor, price)` creates a new object with the right values.

The most important part about unit tests is this flow:

-> General idea
-> Logic performed
-> End situation reached

Your situation fills this in as

-> I want to test `createProgram` with variables X, Y and Z
-> ??
-> The database should return a program that has values X, Y and Z

All together you don't really care what happens in the second step, as long as the end result works. For this reason you can allow more general tests in your code that basically perform logic and check if the result of all that equals your desired output.

The obvious issue with this is ofcourse: in the case of an error, won't this mean I have to manually debug to find the issue? Yes, it does. That's why you should add many smaller tests (like testing the constructor) to help pinpoint the exact issue.

There certainly is nothing wrong with using getters and setters. In fact, you will most certainly need them. It's about testing workflow, not necessarily testing isolated methods.

Comment: But isn't that more of an integration test than a unit test though? It's not about me wanting to avoid using getters and setters, it's about me wanting to avoid testing anything other than the object under test.

Comment: It definitely is more of an integration test, but what would you exactly test in a method that merely delegates an action to a method in another class? You can safely assume that calling a method with a few parameters will work as intended: the method will be called with those parameters. If you want to perform logic on these parameters then you're in the wrong method to test.

Comment: Good point; there isn't a whole lot of logic in this particular method. I'm still kind of curious though as to whether it's possible to test a method like this without having to rely on the correctness of the class it creates (`Program`).